# Cron expression for 10 AM on Monday to Friday except last day of month

Tags: cron, uipath

```
0 0 10 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *
```

This is 10 AM on Monday to Friday.
Is it possible to set except the last day of month for the expression above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with 3 rules:

```
0 0 30 4,6,9,11        *
0 0 31 1,3,5,7,8,10,12 *
0 0 28 2               *
```

Or simply on the first of each month:

```
0 0 1 * *
```